# Is there a way to avoid the flickering between rendering of the plots using shiny recalculate

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to avoid the flickering between rendering of the plots using shiny recalculate ?

The plots become grey-on-invalidation mechanism (flashing) the moment they are invalidated (which in our case means when values$a has changed), so their current display is not up to date, but they also have not finished recalculating for the new value of values$a. We can speed up recalculation (by parallelizing code), but never completely get rid of it. So removing this mechanism actually removes information from the end user, as you now don't have any way to know if the plot is still up to date or if it's recalculating for the next value... I understand this may be annoying, but I just want to make sure you understand why it's happening.

Appreciate your time for reading this and will be glad if you could suggest some solution.

```
library("shiny")
library("parallel")
library("pryr")
ui <-  basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot1')
  ,plotOutput('plot2')
  ,plotOutput('plot3')
  ,plotOutput('plot4')
  ,plotOutput('plot5')
  ,plotOutput('plot6')
  ,plotOutput('plot7')
  ,plotOutput('plot8')
  ,plotOutput('plot9')
  ,plotOutput('plot10')
  ,plotOutput('plot11')
  ,plotOutput('plot12')
  ,plotOutput('plot13')
  ,plotOutput('plot14')
  ,plotOutput('plot15')
  ,plotOutput('plot16')
  ,plotOutput('plot17')
  ,plotOutput('plot18')
  ,plotOutput('plot19')
  ,plotOutput('plot20')
  ,plotOutput('plot21')
  ,plotOutput('plot22')
  ,plotOutput('plot23')
  ,plotOutput('plot24')
  ,plotOutput('plot25')
  ,plotOutput('plot26')
  ,plotOutput('plot27')
  ,plotOutput('plot28')
  ,plotOutput('plot29')
  ,plotOutput('plot30')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues(a=1) 
  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000)
    
    doPlot<-rnorm(1)
    
    values$a <- doPlot
    print(mem_used())
  })
  
  observeEvent(values$a,{
    mclapply(1:30,function(i){
      output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({plot(rnorm(50),main=i)})
    })  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)


##################################

library("shiny")
library("parallel")
library("pryr")

ui <-  basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot1')
  ,plotOutput('plot2')
  ,plotOutput('plot3')
  ,plotOutput('plot4')
  ,plotOutput('plot5')
  ,plotOutput('plot6')
  ,plotOutput('plot7')
  ,plotOutput('plot8')
  ,plotOutput('plot9')
  ,plotOutput('plot10')
  ,plotOutput('plot11')
  ,plotOutput('plot12')
  ,plotOutput('plot13')
  ,plotOutput('plot14')
  ,plotOutput('plot15')
  ,plotOutput('plot16')
  ,plotOutput('plot17')
  ,plotOutput('plot18')
  ,plotOutput('plot19')
  ,plotOutput('plot20')
  ,plotOutput('plot21')
  ,plotOutput('plot22')
  ,plotOutput('plot23')
  ,plotOutput('plot24')
  ,plotOutput('plot25')
  ,plotOutput('plot26')
  ,plotOutput('plot27')
  ,plotOutput('plot28')
  ,plotOutput('plot29')
  ,plotOutput('plot30')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(a=1) 
  
  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000)
    
    doPlot<-rnorm(1)
    
    values$a <- doPlot
    print(mem_used())
  })
  
  mclapply(1:30,function(i){
    output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <<- renderPlot({values$a
      plot(rnorm(50),main=i)
    })
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the recalculating opacity via css, e.g. add the following to your UI code:

```
  tags$style(type="text/css",
             ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"
  )
```

---

Using your example:

```
library("shiny")
library("parallel")
library("pryr")
ui <-  basicPage(
  tags$style(type="text/css",
             ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"
  ),
  plotOutput('plot1')
  ,plotOutput('plot2')
  ,plotOutput('plot3')
  ,plotOutput('plot4')
  ,plotOutput('plot5')
  ,plotOutput('plot6')
  ,plotOutput('plot7')
  ,plotOutput('plot8')
  ,plotOutput('plot9')
  ,plotOutput('plot10')
  ,plotOutput('plot11')
  ,plotOutput('plot12')
  ,plotOutput('plot13')
  ,plotOutput('plot14')
  ,plotOutput('plot15')
  ,plotOutput('plot16')
  ,plotOutput('plot17')
  ,plotOutput('plot18')
  ,plotOutput('plot19')
  ,plotOutput('plot20')
  ,plotOutput('plot21')
  ,plotOutput('plot22')
  ,plotOutput('plot23')
  ,plotOutput('plot24')
  ,plotOutput('plot25')
  ,plotOutput('plot26')
  ,plotOutput('plot27')
  ,plotOutput('plot28')
  ,plotOutput('plot29')
  ,plotOutput('plot30')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues(a=1) 
  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000)
    
    doPlot<-rnorm(1)
    
    values$a <- doPlot
    print(mem_used())
  })
  
  observeEvent(values$a,{
    mclapply(1:30,function(i){
      output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({plot(rnorm(50),main=i)})
    })  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```